# How to redirect to another page using Scala Template

Tags: html, scala, playframework-2.0

I have two html pages: `/algorithrms` and `/algorithms/add` written in scala template. The route file contains following lines:

```
GET     /algorithms                 controllers.Application.algorithms()
GET     /algorithms/add             controllers.Application.newAlgorithmForm()
```

I want to add a button in the page `/algorithms` and when I click that button, it simply redirects to the second page `/algorithms/add`. I know how to do this in JavaScript. I just want to call an action from the button click and then let the action redirects me to the landing page.

So I added the following code in the first page's html template:

```
    @form(action=routes.Application.newAlgorithmForm()){
        <input type="submit" value="Add">
    }
```

It worked, but the landing url is: `http://localhost:9000/algorithms/add?`

I don't want that question mark. I want to know 1) what I did wrong to cause the question mark to generate and 2) how to remove it?

Comment: If you eventually will send information with the form (have some other form fields) you could define the `add` method as a `POST` instead of a `GET`. Otherwise you can follow adis' advise.

Comment: @EECOLOR NO, I won't send info with the form. So you are right, adis' solution is what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know if you use Twitter bootstrap, but hyperlinks can look like buttons too, and the `redirect to another page` sounds to me like a plain hyperlink:

```
<a class="btn" href="@controllers.routes.Application.newAlgorithmForm()" >
  @Messages("add.newAlgorithmForm")
</a>
```

Comment: I haven't used bootstrap but I just gave it a try with my code. It works very well. Thanks!